# ListPreference vs RingtonePreference in PreferenceFragment during Rotation

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've got the following question: I'm running Android 4.4. I programmed an PreferenceFragment that displays two settings: One ListPreference and one RingtonePreference. The ListPreference entries and entryValues are taken from a two arrays defined in values/array. The displaying and selecting works fine. The Fragment is called from a simple Activity.

However, I've got the following problem:

If I open the RingtonePreference and rotate my device, then the displayed dialog stays up. If I do the same thing with the ListPreference, then the dialog disappears. Here, it does not matter if I set retainInstanceState to true or false. Moreover, if I try to keep the Fragment after rotation, then the App will crash, as the activity was re-created. However, I assume that the Context of the ListPreference was not refreshed. As I never passed any context here, I don't know, how I can get the wished result:

My goal: Both dialogs should keep alive after orientation change.

Best regards,
mister-viper